# How to build an application written in C#, using Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, build

I have a repo with code written in C# and I want to understand how we proceed with building the .dlls and finally reach to the final working application.

What I want to understand is which is the process/ logic we follow to build the final application. For example the repository has too many solutions inside the repository, how can I distinguish which is the first I need to build and do I have to follow a specific order?

Please let me know if you have any suggestions or tutorials, as I am new to this and I am trying to learn.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The main project has links to other projects.  Building the main should automatically build other projects and copy the dll to the main project bin folder.  The main project is the one that is not a child of any other project.

Answer (score 3):

This is far too broad of a question to provide any kind of decent answer.

There's a plethora of tutorials and guides on the internet for how to start out in c# and VS 2022.

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/getting-started/

As a small attempt to point you in the right direction...

I'm not really sure what "too many projects" means. If you downloaded a repo it's possible that they're all needed. They likely reference each other in order to have all of the code it needs to compile and run. For example, you could have a DAL layer (data access layer), Business Layer, and a UI layer. You could even have multiple UI layers, or separate projects that consume various parts of the project for various reasons. That is, you could have a project that contains a bunch of timers that monitor changes in your application and they're deployed separately from the rest of the app, etc. There's really no telling what's going on without seeing the project or repo you downloaded.

What happens when you build the project? Does it compile? If not, does it use nuget packages that aren't being restored? Maybe that needs to be enabled.

If it does build, and you want to run it, then you need to figure out which project is the "UI" project and set that as the starting project.

Again, this is a very broad question, and you'd be best served by reading a few tutorials and then coming back with specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are already detailed.

C# Forms Project:

Creating Windows Forms Applications in Visual Studio Using C#.

First, you will create a C# application project. The project type provides all the template files needed before adding anything.

1. Open Visual Studio 2022.
2. In the Start window, select Create New Project.

[image]

3. On the Create New Project window, select the Windows Forms App (.NET Framework) template for C#.(If you like, you can refine your search to quickly find the template you want. For example, enter or type Windows Forms App in the search box. Next, select C# from the Language list, then Windows from the Platform list .)

[image]

4. In the Configure New Project window, type or enter HelloWorld in the Project Name box. Then, choose Create.

[image]

Create an application

After you select the C# project template and name the file, Visual Studio opens a form for you. Forms are the Windows user interface. We'll create a "Hello World" application by adding controls to the form, and then run the application.

Add a button to the form

1. Select Toolbox to open the Toolbox popup.(If you don't see the Toolbox pop-up option, you can open it from the menu bar. To do this, click View > Toolbox. Or press Ctrl+Alt+X.)

[image]

2. Select the Dock icon to dock the Toolbox window.
3. Select the button control and drag it onto the form.

[image]

4. In the Properties window, find Text, change the name from Button1 to click it, and press Enter.(If you don't see the Properties window, you can open it from the menu bar. To do this, choose View > Properties Window. Or press F4. )

[image]

Add the code to the form

1. In the Form1.cs [Design] window, double-click the "Click this button" to open the Form1.cs window. (Alternatively, you can expand Form1.cs in Solution Explorer and select Form1.)
2. In the Form1.cs window, write the code: MessageBox.Show("Hello World"); as shown in the following picture:

[image]

Run the application: Select the Start button to run the application.

[image]

Close the Form1 dialog to stop the application from running.